# Why is my partner's iphone safari history showing up on my macbook history?

Tags: iphone, icloud, safari, history

For some weird reason my partner's iphone safari history is showing up on my macbook's safari?
Only my phone is connected to my macbook (for imessages and icloud), so I can't understand how his history is showing up when mine isn't?
How is this possible?
He has used his phone as a hotspot before and logged into his icloud for itunes once but his history has been showing up way before then?
Please help clarify to stop this!

Comment: Do you use the same iCloud accounts? Do you use the same Apple ID? If so, theres problem #1.

Comment: When he is buying your birthday present tell him to use private browsing!

Comment: No, two different accounts!

Comment: Seriously, has he used the mac for backup and it is trusted? I think that can be unlinked...

Comment: Solar Mike - No he's never used my mac to back up. I'm wondering maybe whether he's plugged his phone in to charge once and he's clicked "trust this computer"??

Answer (score 1):

To check and control which devices are trusted on your mac or apple ID, go to System Preferences and click iCloud

Then via the Account Details button, select the devices tab, from here you can control which devices are trusted.